# Question about convex set?

Tags: general-topology

Can someone prove or give me a counterexample that is for a set $A$, if the closure of $A$ is convex then the interior of $A$ is also convex?

Comment: This is really quite false; think about intervals contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $A = (0,1) \cup (1,2)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $A=[0,1)\cup (1,2]$. Clearly, $\text{cl}(A)=[0,2]$ is convex, but $\text{int}(A)=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is NOT convex. For example, $0.5$ and $1.5\in A$, but $0.5\times 0.5+0.5\times 1.5=1\notin A$.